# Efficient way to remove element from a list at specified indices

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

Let's say I have a list of N elements (`list1`).

I have then a list of M <= N elements containing all the indices of elements that I want to remove from the other list (`list2`).

I want to delete elements on `list1` accordingly with `list2` indices in the most efficient way possible.

First approach was through a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
    list1.RemoveAt(list2[i]);
```

This work pretty good (I need `list2` to be ordered, of course) but has an O(M*N) complexity in worst case (M iterations, O(n) for `RemoveAt`)

Another solution was to create a temporary list, populate it with elements that should *not* be deleted and then use the LINQ intersect method

```
List<T> tempList = new List<T>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    if (list2.Contains(i))
        tempList.Add(list1[i]);
list1.Intersect(tempList);
```

While at first I was excited by the O(N+M) complexity of the `Intersect`, I eventually realized that I need at first N iterations to populate the `tempList` and then any advantages goes lost (let us assume that list2 is an `HashSet` in this second case I don't care about ordering but just about O(1) `Contains`)

After some digging, still I wasn't able to find a way to perform a `RemoveAll` like method that removes all the elements from `list1` accordigly to values stored in `list2`.

Is it there any chance to get it as performant as possible?

PS: for all the ones that will think "premature optimization is the root of all evil", please consider that my code is actually working fine but, as I am working on a strictly time dependend problem, saving few ns each iteration (and I am going to have around 150k iterations) can lead to a significant improvement.

EDIT: as @InBetween correctly pointed out, having an `Intersect` on second solution is actually useless, reducing it the complexity goes down.

Comment: Optimization is the root of fun, IMHO. Premature or not! So can we assume `list2` is already sorted?

Comment: We can assume a lot of things about `list2`. We can assume it is sorted, or it is an `HashSet`. I have control over `list2` and how it is created, so I can do a lot of interesting things over it. But I agree with you, optimization is cool!

Comment: Why are you intersecting? Keep the newly created list.

Comment: @InBetween Because at first it was an except, than an intesection, and then I lost track of what I was doing, but you are right (still, this doesn't seem the best way to do that to me)

Comment: The first approach with a `LinkedList` instead of a `List` is `O(n)` since the remove operation becomes O(1)

Comment: @SimpleVar I am aware of this, but I have (somewhere in the code) a lot of random accessed (more that deletions) that actually make `List` a better choice over `LinkedList`

Comment: If `list2` is ordered, you can make it pretty fast modifying your second solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List1 = Enumerable.Range(0,List1.Count).Except(List2).Select(i=>List1[i]).ToList()
```

or

```
bool[] shouldWeSayGoodbye = new bool[List1.Count];
for(var i=0;i<List2.Count;i++){
   shouldWeSayGoodbye[List2[i]]=true;
}

typeof_list1 List3 = new List<typeof_list1>();
for(var i=0;i<List1.Count;i++){
   if(!shouldWeSayGoodbye[i]){
      List3.Add(List1[i])
   }
}
```

some testing shows the loop beats Linq  x4 times at least.

Comment: Very cool answer, quite obscure. Do you mind explaining why is it performant?

Comment: Because deleting an element forces list to move every element after it. And producing a new list is way faster.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082042/how-to-remove-from-listt-efficiently-c

Comment: @Fylax This is basically the LINQ version of your second solution removing the unnecessary `Except`.

Comment: @InBetween I figured out what is this (and you already pointed out that there was an exceeding `Intersect` that actually had no sense and I agreed with you), but still it is not clear to me why it is more performant. As I explained in my question, saving ns is a huge improvement, and in my experience LINQ tends to be slower than a for loop

Comment: Well then keep the basic concept - you are to find the indexes of the items to stay and produce a new list of them. Removing items from the list will be slower.

Comment: After your edit there is no reason to write a new answer. My idea was just to change list2 structure so that it is what you called `shallWeSayGoodby` from the start. Seems to be the most efficient and clean way to perform this task

Answer (score 2):

If `list2` is ordered, then simply use your second solution optimized:

```
var exceptIndex = 0;
var newList = new List<T>();

for (var i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
{
    if (i != list2[exceptIndex]) newList.Add(list1[i]);
    else exceptIndex++
}

return newList;
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I realized I way that merges your solutions to a new one: having list2 as a boolean array which says which indices should be kept and which not. This goes far away from my initial question, though.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.Add` is actually `O(1)` if the the capacity is not exceeded.
Here's what I came up with, should go at `O(n)`:

```
List<T> resultList = new List<T>(list1.Count); // high capacity!
int curIdx = list1.Count - 1; // start at the end of list1

// assumes list2 is sorted descendingly
list2.Add(-1); // add a final -1 index to make following code nicer

foreach (int targetIdx in list2)
{
    while (curIdx > targetIdx)
    {
        resultList.Add(list1[curIdx]); // both operations are O(1)
        curIdx--;
    }
    curIdx--;
}

// resultList is reversed
```

---

Clarification:

> list1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 
>   list2: [1, 3] 
>   wanted result: [10, 12, 14]

We want `list2` to be sorted desc, and add a final -1 to it:

> list2: [3, 1, -1]

And the final result would actually be the wanted result in reverse. Reversing the list afterwards can be done in `O(n)` so it does not change overall complexity, however you can optimize the code further so the final list is actually in correct order (home work!)

Comment: Even though you see a while within a foreach - we really do only loop over n elements

Comment: Using a backward for loop would made my final list in correct order, I guess. But final order is not actually a big deal, as I said before, I do a lot of random access (be aware of random), so it would just increase the entropy.

Plus, I am aware of the capacity costraint. I tried all possible tricks all over my code to increase performances :)

Anyway thank to you all, I found a quite nice and efficient solution (which massively changes list2 though)

Comment: @Fylax, care to share your solution ?

Comment: Sure, it was in my plan.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to stick with your `for` loops. They are going to be the fastest, assuming the `list2` is sorted in reverse order (for your example).

You could try using `RemoveAll` perhaps...

```
list1.RemoveAll(l1item => list2.Contains(list1.IndexOf(l1item)));
```

The downside is, while this looks cleaner and more straightforward, the underpinnings of it are actually fairly complex.

```
public int RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (match == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    int num = 0;
    while (num < this._size && !match(this._items[num]))
    {
        num++;
    }
    if (num >= this._size)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int i = num + 1;
    while (i < this._size)
    {
        while (i < this._size && match(this._items[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (i < this._size)
        {
            this._items[num++] = this._items[i++];
        }
    }
    Array.Clear(this._items, num, this._size - num);
    int result = this._size - num;
    this._size = num;
    this._version++;
    return result;
}
```

On the other hand, looking at `RemoveAt` which you are currently using:

```
public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    if (index >= this._size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    this._size--;
    if (index < this._size)
    {
        Array.Copy(this._items, index + 1, this._items, index, this._size - index);
    }
    this._items[this._size] = default(T);
    this._version++;
}
```

This performs an `Array.Copy` each time an item is removed while the `RemoveAll` works through the items and shifts indexed items up over the "removed" item.

You could run some simple benchmark tests on both of those and see which is better.

Using the following though, might give you the best results:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
   bool exists = false;
   for (int j = 0; j < list2.Count; j++)
      if (i == list2[j]) 
      {
         exists = true;
         break;
      }
   if (!exists) newList.Add(list1[i]);
}
```

This should not have any dependency on list order.